# Does NxM multiplication require partial products to be > N+M width?

Tags: math, multiplication

I'm working with one of the [Synopsys DesignWare multiplier IPs](https://www.synopsys.com/dw/ipdir.php?c=DW02_mult). It takes in two inputs of width `N` and `M` and outputs two partial products of width `N+M+2` that the user must add together to obtain the final product. It supports both signed and unsigned sources via toggling another input bit.

I can't seem to figure out why the partial products require `N+M+2` width. Why should it not be just `N+M`? I have searched on binary multiplication with partial products and I have not found any evidence that could explain this. Everything points to the product being N+M. I also could not find any explanation in the Synopsys spec other than `N+M+2` being a 'requirement' for the outputs. Is this just a vendor-specific quirk or is there some arithmetic reasoning behind it?